# Converting SPOT 4 level 1A from TOA reflectance to Surface Reflectance in ENVI

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, reflectance

I downloaded the SPOT scene Level 1A: Reflectance at the top of the Atmosphere, not orthorectified to use in land use and land cover mapping applications. I would like to convert them to Surface reflectance to use in the classification. What method can I use in band math?

I checked on the metadata but it is not clear how to rescale or which values should be used.

I read on https://swh-2a-carto.fr/faq but they did not mention how to rescale to SR. I also read this article [https://web.archive.org/web/20170809140059/http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~grewe/pubs/DistSensorNetworkBook2011/Atmosphere/Haxe_MultiSpectralData2_Filtering.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809140059/http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/%7Egrewe/pubs/DistSensorNetworkBook2011/Atmosphere/Haxe_MultiSpectralData2_Filtering.pdf) but it is only on SPOT 5 and 6.

Any advice?